# C# - Windows Store app 8.1 ListView defaults to 2nd value

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps

So I have 2 listview. The main one contains the hours of the day the other has the day of the week.

If I select an item from the hours listView it easily selects the right day 
but when I put the code in for selecting the right hour from the selected day it goes wrong. 
The first option(Today) will selected the correct hour, the next one (tomorrow) will also be selected fine. But when I try any of the days after tomorrow it goes wrong. I have debugged it and found that it runs through the method fine and selects the right hour but then the method runs again and defaults the selection back to the second option(Tomorrow). That happens no matter what other day I click on(Excluding Today).

This is the C# code I used for selecting the day

```
switch (lvi.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        gridPanels.SelectedIndex = hourIndex[0];
        break;
    case 1:
        gridPanels.SelectedIndex = hourIndex[1];
        break;
    case 2:
        gridPanels.SelectedIndex = hourIndex[2];
        break;
    case 3:
        gridPanels.SelectedIndex = hourIndex[3];
        break;
    case 4:
        gridPanels.SelectedIndex = hourIndex[4];
        break;
}
```

// In the XAML Im using SelectionChanged="Method_Name"

Note: I have checked via the debugger that my hourIndex[] has the correct values I want

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in XAML-based technologies. That's what XAML is for. Create a proper ViewModel and use DataBinding and all your problems will magically disappear.

Comment: Just wondering I havent seen any use of viewmodels in any of the Windows 8.1 store apps. I did google it and it comes up as the MVVM. Should I be using that?